# Conditions for positive eigenfunctions

Tags: differential-equations

Where can I find precise conditions under which an elliptic eigenvalue problem in n independent variables has a positive eigenfunction?

Comment: Perhaps H. Amann's paper _Maximum principles and principal eigenvalues_, in: Ten Mathematical Essays on Approximation in Analysis and Topology, Elsevier, 2004, could be of some help.